# Can I create and use my own Ansible modules?

Tags: ansible

When standard Ansible modules are not enough it is possible to create your own modules.

How do I create such a module and how do I add and use it in my own Ansible repository? I don't want to contribute back to Ansible core, I just want to enhance my own Ansible repository with concepts that are only relevant to my specific situation.

Comment: Yes you can. The tuto is maybe a little bit too long to reproduce here, but: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the [different possibilities to include custom modules locally](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#developing-locally), you can include your custom module in `library` directory residing at the same level as your playbook or in a top level role directory for easier distribution between internal projects.

Writing the module itself is covered by a rather comprehensive [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#developing-modules-general). You can also find a multitude of examples on the net (search for "ansible custom modules"). I'll only give a single example I liked: [build a custom module in 10 minutes](https://blog.toast38coza.me/custom-ansible-module-hello-world/)